# Not sending emails to particular domains from Salesforce

Tags: email, workflowoutboundmessage, massemailmessage

I have a requirement that I don't want to send emails to some particular domain's from Salesforce.

My org is not allowed to send emails to some domains , and we send a lot of emails from Salesforce .

So , is there a way in which I can save a list of domains in Salesforce and whenever I,am sending the emails from Salesforce to multiple email addresses then at the time of sending ,it removes the email addresses those that have the domain similar to anyone present in blacklisted domains from sent list.

or

While adding the emails to the sent list it asks me to remove the blacklisted domain email addresses and tells me which all email addresses belong to the blacklisted domain.

Comment: How are you sending those emails?

Comment: @SebastianKessel , we are using exact target , send email buttons on campaigns

Comment: @SebastianKessel , we are also sending emails using mass emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this use a standard field in Salesforce. Their is a field in Salesoforce called "EmailOptOut" . 
If this is checked then no mass emails are sent to the record with this checkbox checked.

We can add the blacklisted domain in the custom setting and whenevr the record is created of updated we can check if it has a blacklisted domain the check off the "Email opt out" checkbox which does not allow to send any email from Salesforce for that particular record.